# Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor' while deploying grails application on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, grails, hsqldb

I am trying to deploy my grails(2.2.1) application on tomcat 7.0.42. So I followed the steps as given in this [link](http://grails.org/Deployment) from grails website. But when I try to start the application from Tomcat Web Application Manager, I see the following error log on the tomcat console:

```
    Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean
property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.fa
ctory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties'
: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property
 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframew
ork.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectD
etector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframew
ork.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaDat
a; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
 PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already in use: "Locked by another p
rocess". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode
[90020-164])
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error crea
ting bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sess
ionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is or
g.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' wh
ile setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springf
ramework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hib
ernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while sett
ing bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wi
th name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extractin
g DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedExcepti
on: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already in use: "Lo
cked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use
 the server mode [90020-164])
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessio
nFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.
springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with na
me 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' whil
e setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springfra
mework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hiber
nateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while settin
g bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is o
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
 name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is o
rg.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting
DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException
: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already in use: "Lock
ed by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use t
he server mode [90020-164])
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateP
roperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception i
s org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean w
ith name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetecto
r' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested
 exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error cre
ating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested
 exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error wh
ile extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQL
NestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be alread
y in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other conne
ction(s); use the server mode [90020-164])
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'diale
ctDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect
]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method faile
d; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:
 Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons
.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may
be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all ot
her connection(s); use the server mode [90020-164])
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested ex
ception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while
 extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNes
tedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already i
n use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connecti
on(s); use the server mode [90020-164])
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while
 extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNes
tedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already i
n use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connecti
on(s); use the server mode [90020-164])
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableCon
nectionFactory (Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Pos
sible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-164])

        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFacto
ry(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSou
rce.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource
.java:1044)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked
 by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the
 server mode [90020-164]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
        at org.h2.store.FileLock.getExceptionAlreadyInUse(FileLock.java:439)
        at org.h2.store.FileLock.lockFile(FileLock.java:336)
        at org.h2.store.FileLock.lock(FileLock.java:128)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:542)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:222)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:217)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:159)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:138)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:121)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.jav
a:305)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:110)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:94)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(Driv
erConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(Poolable
ConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(Bas
icDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFacto
ry(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 5 more
2013-08-31 19:17:32,185 [http-apr-8081-exec-4] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader
  - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager
PostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springfra
mework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trans
actionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting
bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.fa
ctory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Can
not resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property
'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.Bea
nCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot
resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'propert
ies' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans
.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector':
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.
support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested
 exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create Poolable
ConnectionFactory (Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process".
Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-16
4])
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error crea
ting bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sess
ionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is or
g.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' wh
ile setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springf
ramework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hib
ernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while sett
ing bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wi
th name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extractin
g DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedExcepti
on: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already in use: "Lo
cked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use
 the server mode [90020-164])
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessio
nFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.
springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with na
me 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' whil
e setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springfra
mework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hiber
nateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while settin
g bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is o
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
 name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is o
rg.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting
DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException
: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already in use: "Lock
ed by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use t
he server mode [90020-164])
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateP
roperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception i
s org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean w
ith name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetecto
r' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested
 exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error cre
ating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested
 exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error wh
ile extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQL
NestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be alread
y in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other conne
ction(s); use the server mode [90020-164])
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'diale
ctDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect
]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method faile
d; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:
 Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons
.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may
be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all ot
her connection(s); use the server mode [90020-164])
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested ex
ception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while
 extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNes
tedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already i
n use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connecti
on(s); use the server mode [90020-164])
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while
 extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNes
tedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already i
n use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connecti
on(s); use the server mode [90020-164])
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableCon
nectionFactory (Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Pos
sible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-164])

        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFacto
ry(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSou
rce.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource
.java:1044)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked
 by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the
 server mode [90020-164]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
        at org.h2.store.FileLock.getExceptionAlreadyInUse(FileLock.java:439)
        at org.h2.store.FileLock.lockFile(FileLock.java:336)
        at org.h2.store.FileLock.lock(FileLock.java:128)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:542)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:222)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:217)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:159)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:138)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:121)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.jav
a:305)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:110)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:94)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(Driv
erConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(Poolable
ConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(Bas
icDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFacto
ry(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 5 more
Aug 31, 2013 7:17:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Aug 31, 2013 7:17:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/BskDPP2013ExcelImportToDatabase-0.1] startup failed due to pre
vious errors
Aug 31, 2013 7:17:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearRefere
ncesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/BskDPP2013ExcelImportToDatabase-0.1] registered th
e JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web applicati
on was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unre
gistered.
```

The application, when run via run-app command(in intellij) works fine.

Also if we see this line from the log:`Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-164])`,it says that the database is being used by some other process. However that can not happen because the database is HSQLDB which is internal with the grails application and no other external DBMS is being used.

I would surely upvote(and accept also if its the ultimate) any solution which solves(or atleast gives a direction to solve) the above issue.

**EDIT:**
Here is my DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"

        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:file:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show `DataSource.groovy`.

Comment: Do you have other grails applications deployed to Tomcat with the same configuration? Can you try changing the in-memory `prodDb` to `prodDb1` for example and then deploy to Tomcat for use?

Comment: @dmahapatro no I have no other grails applications deployed in Tomcat. Also I tried changing prodDb to prodDb1. But the same consequence.

Answer (score 1):

```
url = "jdbc:h2:file:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
```

refers to a H2 `file` database. Can you try using in memory `prodDb` instead if the intention was not to refer to a file database?

```
url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
```

Comment: Are you referring to  url = "jdbc:h2:mem:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"...'mem' is missing in above answer...

Answer (score 1):

because the "grails war" command generate war file using by default the **production** environment that is defined in the **DataSource.groovy**. Maybe the production DB is no working yet, so you can try to run "grails test war" to build war with your Test DB.